# How to analytically solve a Second Order ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I got the following ODE in my work. I haven't seen ODEs carrying trigonometric functions this way. See if anyone could help on solving it analytically. Here is the ODE

$y''(x)+\sqrt{2} c \tanh \left(\dfrac{c x}{3 \sqrt{2}}\right) y'(x)=0$ where $c>0.$ The boundary conditions could be $y(\infty)=0, y(0)=1.$

Comment: Reduce the order: set $w = y'.$

Comment: Nice. The BC at infinity is an issue, @SeanRoberson

Comment: $\tanh$ is not trigonometric but hyperbolic.

Comment: That was my bad

Comment: The general linear second-order DE cannot be solved by quadratures.  However, this one is missing the $y$ term, so you can solve it by successively solving two first-order linear DEs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Letting $u(x)=y'(x)$ and $m={{c}\over 3\sqrt2}\space$yields;

$$u'(x)+{\sqrt{2}c \tanh(mx)}\cdot u(x)=0$$

Creating an integrating factor, $\mu(x)$, gives us;

$$\mu(x)=e^{\sqrt{2}c\int{\tanh(mx)}dx}=e^{6\cdot {\ln(\cosh(mx))}}$$

$$\therefore \mu(x)=(\cosh(mx))^{6}$$

Multiplying our equation by this integrating factor yields;

$$(\cosh(mx))^{6}\cdot u'+{\sqrt{2}c\tanh(mx)}\cdot(\cosh(mx))^{6}\cdot u=0$$

Which can be rewritten thusly;

$${d\over dx}\big((\cosh(mx))^{6}\cdot u(x)\big)=0$$

Integrating on both sides and a quick back-substitution reveals;

$$u(x)=y'(x)={C\over(\cosh(mx))^{6}}$$

$$\therefore y(x)=C\int{(\cosh(mx))^{{-6}}}dx$$

Here I must admit to a certain amount of laziness. This integral is quite doable but tedious in the extreme... The final result is;

$$y(x)=C \cdot {{\sqrt{2}\tanh(mx)\cdot(3\tanh^4(mx)-10\tanh^2(mx)+15)}\over5c}+D$$

Finally, applying your boundary conditions reveals that $(D=1)$ and $(C={-5c\over 8\sqrt{2}})$;

$$\therefore y(x)= {{-\tanh\big({{cx}\over 3\sqrt2}\big)\big(3\tanh^4\big({{cx}\over 3\sqrt2}\big)-10\tanh^2\big({{cx}\over 3\sqrt2}\big)+15\big)}\over  8}+1$$

Comment: You should reduce expressions that are simultaneously in $c$ and $m$, like $\frac{\sqrt2c}{m}=6$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Fair enough... I was trying to maintain notational consistency until the end but you're right; less writing is usually desirable.

Comment: Thank you all for your nice comments and a wonderful answer @All